# SQL Performance tuning

Tags: sql

is there any way to find the long running queries at particular point of time?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: For which RDMS as SQL tag on this website means ANSI/ISO SQL standard..

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a query you can use to find which queries are running and consuming more time.

```
 SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
    WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
    ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
    END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
    qs.total_worker_time,
    qs.last_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
    ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
    -- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
    -- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

This would be the query result:
[image]

Also refer to this link: 
https://stackify.com/performance-tuning-in-sql-server-find-slow-queries/

Comment: We don;t know which RDBMS we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL or Maria DB. Basically you can use this query;

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE time > ** choose time in seconds **
```